# How to use /dist folder files created by angular-cli ng build command to create an app that can be run by itself?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In order to see the `ng build` result, I need to run `ng serve`, but how that helps me to create an angular2 project that I can run in any web hosting? my web hosting don't know angular2 or `ng serve` command. What did I miss in this process?

Please advise how after using angular-cli (which is a great tool) I'm now ready to updload files to any web hosting and see my app running. I thought if I run the "**index.html**" file I get app that runs and not depeneding on any commands :-/

This is the resuilt of index.html:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ng serve : in memory (local) development
ng build : creates a distributable stand-alone app in your dist folder.

So run a ng build and copy the contents of the dist folder to any remote server and it should run (need to run it in the root btw, if you want to run your app in a subfolder on your remote server, do a ng build --base-href myapp --prod)

Comment: How it runs if it can't find the files

Comment: Where on the server are the contents of the dist folder? Is in in a subfolder?

Comment: In other words, what is the URL you use to request the index.html file? Exactly?

Comment: it worked. I just needed to change the <base href="./"> url

Comment: I am facing the similar issue but i was not able to resolve the issue as per recommended above

Comment: What did you change the path to on your base? The location of the dist folder?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run it directly from the dist folder

```
ng build --base-href .
```

The dot "." in the end will help you run it locally.